# Will the new compiler give access to pointer arithmetic like that done in C?

Tags: compiler

I was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_Cu2T-6Eoo&t=1148) and came across the `Handle` type construct in the new compiler.

So my question is the new `Handle[...]` type in the compiler like a pointer in C? So will this allow the pointer arithmetic as it is possible in C? Can someone provide examples of using this?

I am still using `12.0` and haven't updated yet. Is it already available in version `12.1.1`?

---

Today (Dec 16, 2020) version `12.2` has been released. Those who have updated it please check if they can find `Handle` in there?

Comment: I can't find anything like that in 12.2.0.0, including other contexts and undocumented functions.

Comment: @flinty Are there any new `DataStructure`s created using the new compiler in `12.2`?